# How to move rows up/down on button press in devexpress gridcontrol using c#

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, row, swap

I have a devexpress gridcontrol full of data.  Next to the grid are up and down buttons.  When the user presses one of the buttons, I want the selected row to move up/down.  What are some ways I could go about this?  I wanted to access the row index, but it doesn't appear to be a property of the gridview.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the focused row by its handle you can use the [GridView.FocusedRowHandle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic) property.  Please review the [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642) article for more details.
For moving row focus within the gridview from code-behind I suggest you use a special methods described in the [Moving Row Focus](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1028) help-article:

```
void btnFocusNextRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gridView1.MoveNext();
}
```